# Swaping views with a custom tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tabs

I need to make a custom Tab Bar at the top of my screen using **Im using Xcode and Objective-C**. I tried using Segmented Control and Tab Bar, however i had no success. Here is a picture of:
[how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuqnV.jpg)

I need to make that Tab there, where it shows "Mapas" and "Lista de Lojas" when the user touches the Mapas tab it should show a map with the current location and when the user touches the Lista de Lojas it should show the other view **I already have the Lista de Lojas view prepared, if needed i'll post the .m and .h of that view.** Can anyone help me? Even if you can't, it would also help if you could hint me on what i should search for. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you can simply use two button with round corners at the top of your controller and then use visibility of your map or your listView.
When user tap on 'Mapa' you can start the location, `map.hidden=NO`, etc....
when user tap on 'Lista de Lojas' you can set `map.hidden=YES`, `yourListView.hidden=NO` and `yourListView.reloadData()`.

good luck